# Determines the number of characters in a string X which do not exist in another string Y in assembly code

Tags: c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I've been practicing lately on assembly programming. It seems good until I had this kind of exercise:

> **Write an assembler program (intel 8086) that determines the number of characters in a string X which do not exist in another string Y.
>
>   Ex: X = jason and Y = bacon -> displays 2 (because only the characters
>   ‘j’ and 's' in X are not in Y).
>
>   Ex: X = tony and Y = anthony ->
>   displays 0 (because all the characters of X exist in Y).**

I'm having difficulties in initializing edi after finding a common character between the two strings in order to compare the characters of X with Y (from the beginning of Y) or after not finding, incrementing ebx and skips to other character of X to compare with all of Y's (from first character)

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char string[20] = "jason";
    char string1[20] = "bacon";
    char* c;
    char* p;
    c = string1;
    p = string;
    int x = strlen(string);
    int y = strlen(string1);

    __asm
    {
        mov esi, p;
        mov edi, c;
        mov al, [esi];
        mov ebx, 0;

    look:
        scasb;
        jz exist;
        cmp[edi], '\0';
        jz nonexist;
        jmp look;

    exist:
        dec x;
        mov al, [esi + 1];
        cmp [esi], '\0';
        jz end;
        jmp look;

    nonexist:
        inc ebx;
        dec x;
        mov al, [esi + 1];
        cmp [esi], '\0';
        jz end;
        jmp look;

    end:
        push ebx;
        call Display;
        pop eax;

    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's 32-bit x86, not 8086.  Not that it changes the logic any.  (Although one way to do this exercise is to make bitmaps of which characters were seen in each string and intersect them with NOT + AND.  386 `bts` is a handy way to do `val |= 1<<bitpos`

Comment: You need to search through the entire Y for ***every*** char in X. Therefore you need at least a double loop...